# Which public cloud supports vMotion / live migration to and from a private cloud?

Tags: cloud-computing

Microsoft's Hyper-V has a live migration feature which is similar to VMware's vMotion.  I would assume that one or more public clouds (e.g., AWS, Azure, etc.) have a feature that supports a drag and drop of a server or a Docker container to and from a private cloud.  Is this correct?  If so, which public cloud has the best offering for this ability?  Is Jelastic needed to make this happen?

Comment: This question is asking for ___opinions___ about a feature of a number of services and comparisons between __services__ - this is not within the scope of SR which is about recommending which __Software__ to use for a given set of requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Google and some other cloud providers use live migration for its internal needs, for example for hardware maintenance, but none of them provides live migration from private to public cloud.

Jelastic introduced live migration for end users with help of containers technology. It can be installed on top of many IaaS providers (public or private) or directly on top of bare metal hardware, as result you are able to configure the live migration from private to public cloud or from public to public, for example from AWS to Azure (back and forward).

[image: Live Migration Across the Clouds]

There is a good high level overview of the live migration technology, the problems it solves and possible bottlenecks https://www.infoq.com/articles/container-live-migration